# How to play stream(dash) video in media player

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

The problem is video is not play at all , but when i use http://www.youtubemaza.com/files/data/366/Tom%20And%20Jerry%20055%20Casanova%20Cat%20(1951).mp4 (example) the video player works good.

I'm using json to get url
https://api.vid.me/videos/featured?limit=1

(Current Url **https://api.vid.me/video/18175470/stream?format=dash**)

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private VideoView videoView;
private int position = 0;
private MediaController mediaController;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Set the media controller buttons
    if (mediaController == null) {
        mediaController = new MediaController(MediaPlayerActivity.this);

        // Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController.
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


        // Set MediaController for VideoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    }


    try {

        String videoUrl="https://api.vid.me/video/18175470/stream?format=dash"; // dash

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

   } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoView.requestFocus();


    // When the video file ready for playback.
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {


            videoView.seekTo(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                videoView.start();
            }

            // When video Screen change size.
            mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                    // Re-Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
// When you change direction of phone, this method will be called.
// It store the state of video (Current position)
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Store current position.
    savedInstanceState.putInt("CurrentPosition", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
    videoView.pause();
}


// After rotating the phone. This method is called.
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Get saved position.
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("CurrentPosition");
    videoView.seekTo(position);
}
}
```

xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>-->
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to use a third party library (however this one is done by Google so not sure what you'd call it really...)

http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/

It has very good documentation and even sample code on how to use it with DASH video sources!

Comment: Could you provide some snippet of using DASH to stream videos from URLs?